# how to put Inter-arrival times with mean of 10 seconds

Tags: anylogic

I have a problem with the arrival time of Source in Anylogic.

So the problem state, "Customer arrives with exponentially distributed inter-arrival times with a mean of 10 seconds". So I put "Arrivals defined by" as "Interarrival time" and "Interarrival time" as "exponential(0.167)" with "miniutes". However as I simulated, there seems to be something wrong with the model as it does not generate enough agents.

Is my approach wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

ok.. so to understand the exponential distribution... exponential(1/u) means that the average of interarrivals is 10 seconds with an exponential distribution... so if you use exponential(1/10.0) or exponential(0.1) with seconds instead of minutes it should work.

But what if you want to work in minutes? then the mean interarrival time is 0.167 minutes, which is equal to 10/60 so you have to do in fact exponential(1/0.167) which is more or less exponential(5.99)  and more exactly exponential(1/(10/60.0))

so yes.. there is something wrong with the model :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved my problem. :) I got confused when converting it into unit minutes!

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach, in my opinion, is to use Rate when your inter-arrival time is exponential ([Rate - agents are generated at the specified arrival rate which is equivalent to exponentially distributed interarrival time with mean = 1/rate](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ProcessModeling%2FSource.html])). Just use Rate of 6 agents per minute and done!

Comment: That sounds very simple! So, if it were 6 seconds, that would mean 10 agents per minute, and that would be exponential(10). Now I get it clearly :)